# Greplin Programming Challenge Lv.2

Tags: c#, math, primes, factorization

Challenge located [here](http://challenge.greplin.com/)

Okay so I figured out the number to call in I just don't understand what to do with the result (this could probably have something to do with my limited experince in mathamatics)

so I calc the first Prime fibonacci number larger than the one given over the phone

so lets call that number x

but now I don't under stand the "sum of the prime devisors +1"

as I understand it X is prime so there for the prime devisors are 1 and X

unless its (x+1) to then find the devisors (array D) then find the numbers in D that are prime (array Pd)

Pd1+Pd2= answer

Am I barking up the right tree?

My source code thus far ( I Can provide the is prime code if needed i assume its not)

```
 private static long CalcPassword2(long p)
        {
            p++;
            List<int> factors = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++)
            {
                if (p % i == 0)
                    if (isprime(i))
                    {
                        factors.Add(i);
                    }
            }
            if (factors.Count >= 2)
            {
                factors.Sort();
                factors.Reverse();
                return factors[0]+factors[1];
            }

                return 1;  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I miss read the answer is the sum of all prime factors of the number x

Here is the updated code: (please feel free to comment on the code)

```
private static long CalcPassword2(long p)
        {
            p++;
            List<int> factors = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++)
            {
                if (p % i == 0)
                    if (isprime(i))
                    {
                        factors.Add(i);
                    }
            }
            int answer = 0;
            foreach (int prime in factors)
            {
                answer = answer + prime;
            }
            return answer;
        }
```